# Shapiro Time Delay and Elliptic Integrals

Tags: general-relativity

I have been trying to determine Shapiro's Time Delay in terms of Elliptic Integrals, but getting apparently ERRONEOUS results. I start with the following integral, where b is the impact parameter, c is the speed of light, and $r_{s}$ is the Schwarzchild radius, and $r$ is the radial distance from the massive object.

$$t=\frac{1}{b.c}\int\frac{dr}{(1-\frac{r_{s}}{r})\sqrt{\frac{1}{b^{2}}-\frac{1}{r^{2}}(1-\frac{r_{s}}{r})}}$$

I then manipulate this to the form
$$t=\frac{1}{c}\int\frac{r^{3}dr}{(r-r_{s})\sqrt{r(r^{3}-rb^{2}+b^{2}r_{s})}}$$

I then express the cubic polynomial $r^{3}-rb^{2}+b^{2}r_{s}$ in factor form $(r-r_{0})(r-r_{1})(r-r_{n})$ where $r_{0},r_{1},r_{n}$ are roots of the cubic equation $r^{3}-rb^{2}+b^{2}r_{s}$. When $b>r_{s}*3\sqrt{3}/2$, this cubic polynomial has three roots two positive $r_{0}$ and $r_{1}$,and a negative root $r_{n}=-(r_{0}+r_{1})$. The later is due to the fact there is no $r^{2}$ component in the cubic polynomial . The root $r_{0}$ is the distance of closest approach. The root $r_{1}$ is slightly larger than $r_{s}$ when $r_{0}$ is large. The limits of the integral are from the distance of closest approach $r_{0}$ to earth/mars $r_{e}$ as the case may be. The time taken by the radar there and back will be twice this. The equation (one-way) then becomes

$$t=\frac{1}{c}\int_{r_{0}}^{r_{e}}\frac{r^{3}dr}{(r-r_{s})\sqrt{r(r-r_{0})(r-r_{1})(r+r_{0}+r_{1})}}$$

where $r_{e}>r_{0}>r_{1}>r_{s}>0>-(r_{0}+r_{1})$. Now splitting the integral into parts by using Partial fractions and letting $P=r(r-r_{0})(r-r_{1})(r+r_{0}+r_{1})$ the integral (one-way) then becomes

$$t=\frac{1}{c}\int_{r_{0}}^{r_{e}}\frac{r^{2}dr}{\sqrt{P}}+\frac{r_{s}}{c}\int_{r_{0}}^{r_{e}}\frac{rdr}{\sqrt{P}}+\frac{r_{s}^{2}}{c}\int_{r_{0}}^{r_{e}}\frac{dr}{\sqrt{P}}+\frac{r_{s}^{3}}{c}\int_{r_{0}}^{r_{e}}\frac{dr}{(r-r_{s})\sqrt{P}}$$

FIRST TERM

According to Byrd and Friedman there exists an elliptic recurrence relationship eqn 250.01 whereby the first term of the integral becomes, noting $P(r_{0})=0$

$$\frac{1}{c}.\intop_{r_{0}}^{r_{e}}\frac{r^{2}dr}{\sqrt{P}}=\frac{1}{c}.\frac{\sqrt{P(r_{e})}}{r_{e}}+\frac{1}{c}.\frac{1}{2}\left\{ r_{0}^{2}r_{1}+r_{0}r_{1}^{2}\right\} \intop_{r_{0}}^{r_{e}}\frac{dr}{r\sqrt{P}}$$

The component

$$\frac{1}{c}.\frac{\sqrt{P(r_{e})}}{r_{e}}\longrightarrow\frac{1}{c}.\sqrt{r_{e}^{2}-r_{0}^{2}}\qquad as\quad r_{e}\longrightarrow\infty$$
Namely for large $r_{e}$ the component $\sqrt{P(r_{e})}/r_{e}$ is effectively equivalent to the time taken by the radar beam between the sun and the respective planet in FLAT space (the difference is a fraction of a microsecond). Thus Shapiro's time delay $\triangle t$ can be expressed as [multiply by 2 for there and back between earth and the sun]

$$\triangle t=\frac{1}{c}.\left\{ r_{0}^{2}r_{1}+r_{0}r_{1}^{2}\right\} .\int_{r_{0}}^{r_{e}}\frac{dr}{r\sqrt{P}}+2.\frac{r_{s}}{c}\int_{r_{0}}^{r_{e}}\frac{rdr}{\sqrt{P}}+2.\frac{r_{s}^{2}}{C}\int_{r_{0}}^{r_{e}}\frac{dr}{\sqrt{P}}+2.\frac{r_{s}^{3}}{C}\int_{r_{0}}^{r_{e}}\frac{dr}{(r-r_{s})\sqrt{P}}$$

These integrals are all elliptic integrals, the solution of which can be found in Gradshtein and Ryzhiki (eqns 258.12, 258.11,258.00, and 258.39). The last two terms make contributions of a fraction of a microsecond, and for this purpose I have neglected them. So the excess time delay for the earth-sun leg there and back again is as follows.

$$\triangle t=\frac{1}{c}*g*\left\{ r_{0}+r_{1}\right\} \left\{ r_{0}F(\nu,q)-(r_{0}-r_{1})\prod\left\{ \nu,\frac{r_{1}(2r_{0}+r_{1})}{r_{0}(2r_{1}+r_{0})},q\right\} \right\} +2.\frac{r_{s}}{c}*g*\left\{ (r_{0}-r_{1})\prod(\nu,\frac{2r_{0}+r_{1}}{2r_{1}+r_{0}},q)+r_{1}.F(\nu,q)\right\}$$

where

$$\nu=sin^{-1}\left\{ \sqrt{\frac{(2r_{1}+r_{0})(r_{e}-r_{0})}{(2r_{0}+r_{1})(r_{e}-r_{1})}}\right\}$$

and

$$q=\sqrt{\frac{r_{1}(2r_{0}+r_{1})}{r_{0}(2r_{1}+r_{0})}}$$

and

$$g=\frac{2}{\sqrt{r_{0}(2r_{1}+r_{0})}}$$

Do the same for sun-venus leg there and back again and add it to $\triangle t$ to get the final result.

THE PROBLEM is that when I run a computer program implementing the aforementioned for a earth-sun-venus leg there and back again at superior conjunction, I get a time delay of about 80 microseconds. The experimental results given by Shapiro show 175 microseconds at superior conjunction [See Fig, 6 of 3].

Thus the aforemention formulae DOES NOT AGREE with experimental data. Does anyone have any idea, where and if I made a mistake??? I would be grateful for any contributions. One possible reason is the “spurious” factor 2 is missing, but I believe I have included all these.

1. Handbook of elliptic integrals for engineers and scientists by Byrd, Paul F
   https://archive.org/details/handbookofellipt0000byrd/page/204/mode/2up
   (equation 250.01)
2. Table of Integrals, Series, and Products Seventh Edition, I.S. Gradshteyn and I.M. Ryzhik
   (for equations 258.12, 258.11,258.00,258.39)
   https://archive.org/details/GradshteinI.S.RyzhikI.M.TablesOfIntegralsSeriesAndProducts/mode/2up
3. The Shapiro time delay and the equivalence principle M Possel, Haus der Astronomie and Max Planck Institute for Astronomy, Konigstuhl 17, 69124 Heidelberg, Germany
   https://arxiv.org/pdf/2001.00229.pdf

Comment: What are you taking for the impact parameter $b$ at superior conjunction?

Comment: b is related to the distance of closest approach r0 by b^2=r0^3/(r0 -rs) by virtue of the cubic polynomial. In my computer program I am able to select any value of b. For b= 1 radial sun unit (just grazing the sun) I get Shapiro time delay of 80 microseconds. For b = 50 radial sun units. I get time delay of 64 microseconds.

Comment: The maths above is okay. The problem lay in the software. I used subroutines for the elliptical integrals of the third kind based on "Numerical Recipes in C". However the routine used a different sign convention for the argument n, than used in  "Table of Integrals, Series, and Products" by I.S. Gradshteyn and I.M. Ryzhik. When I changed the sign in the software, I got the desired result.